# Time Series Data - find times of state transition

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, time-series, window-functions

Let's say I have a simple table of the form:

```
<timestamp> <state (A or B)>
```

I want to be able to select all the times when the series transitions from state A to state B (i.e. X<sub>t</sub> = B && X<sub>t-1</sub> = A). For example, with the data:

```
00:00 A
00:01 A
00:02 B
00:03 B
00:04 B
00:05 B
00:06 A
00:07 B
00:08 B
```

I want to return `00:02` and `00:07`.

Maybe I'm searching the wrong keywords, but I can't find any good examples of similar problems. How might I approach this with PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Single time series

```
SELECT ts
FROM  (
   SELECT *, lag(state) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS last_state
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE  state = 'B'
AND    last_state = 'A'
ORDER  BY ts;          -- I assume you want ordered results
```

[@Denis already provided some links.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19307802/939860)

#### Multiple time series

... identified by a `timeseries_id` (answer to comment):

```
SELECT timeseries_id, ts
FROM  (
   SELECT *, lag(state) OVER (PARTITION BY timeseries_id
                              ORDER BY ts) AS last_state
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE  state = 'B'
AND    last_state = 'A'
ORDER  BY timeseries_id, ts;
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow on question: What if multiple time series' are in the same table. The schema is now `<timestamp> <timeseries_id> <state>`. How can I find the transition times for each series?

Comment: @user593062: I added another answer. Start a new question for a new question. You can always link to this one for context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the lead or lag window function:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html